# iCloud is not syncing files within Pages and Numbers folders

Tags: macos, icloud, numbers, pages, catalina

Ever since I upgraded to Catalina, I've had a problem where the files within the Pages and Numbers folders in iCLoud don't sync to my Mac, except for files I've created since the upgrade. However, if I go to iCloud.com I can see everything. I have tried:

1. Turning iCloud on and off again
2. Re-installing Catalina
3. Uninstalling Pages and Numbers (properly, with AppCleaner)

Here are my system specs [image: System specs]
I'll add any more info if needed.

Comment: Are your iOS devices up to date?

Comment: I don't have any

Comment: Ah ok. I’ve had this problem when using different versions of the Mac and iOS apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by signing completely out of iCloud and signing back in.